# No view found for id with LinearLayout and MapView

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm getting an error that states

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e00a7
>   (com.jvlapps.myapp:id/linearLayout1) for fragment ParamMapFragment

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/bannerAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@+string/AdMob_TEST_Unit_Id" />
 <fragment
        android:name="GetMeThere.MainMenuFragment"
        android:id="@+id/MainMenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's ParamMapFragment.cs:

```
public class ParamMapFragment : Fragment
    {
        public string AgencyName => Arguments.GetString("current_agency", "None");

        public ParamMapFragment() { }

        public static ParamMapFragment NewInstance(string currentAgency)
        {
            var bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.PutString("current_agency", currentAgency);
            return new ParamMapFragment { Arguments = bundle };
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            MapView mapView = new MapView(Activity);

            return mapView;
        }

    }
```

Here's the OnCreate of my Activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    var agencyName = Intent.Extras.GetString("current_agency", "None");

    var mapFrag = ParamMapFragment.NewInstance(agencyName);
    FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                    .Add(Resource.Id.linearLayout1, mapFrag, "main_map_fragment")
                    .Commit();
}
```

I've been struggling with this for hours. I have no idea what I'm even doing at this point, or what my app is supposed to do anymore. I'm going to finish making this app, then destroy the universe.

Comment: In which line do you get this error?

Comment: @Mehmed VS says "all threads were executing external code", so I'm not getting a line specifically. But the FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Add... line is where it's happening based on me stepping through a line at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.<resource id of XML above>);` in activity's `OnCreate` method before adding the fragment. Otherwise, your activity doesn't have any content view and cannot find anything for `id/linearLayout1`.